# How to change the Laravel public folder location

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a shared hosting which uses cPanel as its control panel and within the cPanel `public_html` is the default root directory, because of this I can't get my Laravel application work properly.

Is there any way to make Laravel use `public_html` instead of public folder?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Quite easy to find this with a simple search.

See: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5

In your index.php add the following 3 lines.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Edit:

---

As Burak Erdem mentioned, another option (and more preferable) is to put this in the `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` `register()` method.

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // ...

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me: Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in...

Comment: Just by adding that? I'm able switch it around without any errors. Can you post the full error message, it's not telling me much as it is.

Comment: @Robert when I use your solution, it give me error `[ErrorException]                              
  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) `.

Comment: I know it's been quite a while ago, but this question still is high ranked in Google. Therefore I wanted to point out that, for me, these lines of code should be added AFTER the `Turn On The Lights`-section. Then you should update `path.public` to `path.public_html`. At least, that worked for me. :)

Comment: This does not work for laravel-mix, which still compiles assets to the `public` directory.

Comment: This is still the correct solution. I used the second method on 5.7 and it works great!

Comment: This would not work for me until I changed `base_path('public_html')` to `base_path() . '/public_html'`

Comment: "Quite easy to find this with a simple search" Such comments are superfluous. Actually this page shows up as the first result right now.

Answer (score 27):

If Robert's `index.php` solution is not working for you, you can also register the following code at **Application Service Provider** (`App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```

Comment: I prefer use this method. It's worked in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: I prefer this one, because index.php is more likely to be change on framework update

Comment: Is this answer supposed to say `public_html` instead of `public_http`?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.7 and this does not work, is there anything I need to do.

Answer (score 16):

**Server**

Methods described in topic are working just fine, so modyfing App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php register method should do the job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path() . '/public_http';
    });
}
```

**Local php artisan serve development**

However, there is one more issue you can experience. If you're developing your app on local machine and you're using `php artisan serve` command to serve your app you're going to break it with above syntax only. You still need to adjust server.php file which exists in main directory. Edit the contents of it and replace each occurance of `/public` to `/public_html`, so it looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
```

After that. Just stop your server and reload it with `php artisan serve`.

**Front end laravel-mix development**

If you're using webpack and laravel-mix to generate your css and js files then this also needs some update. Without tweaking webpack.mix.js you will end up with something like this on `npm run watch` or `npm run production`:

```
.
..
public
  _html
    js
  public_html
    css
public_html
```

So it's going to mess up your code. To clarify this you have to provide a public path to your webpack.mix.js file. It could look like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public_html/');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

This is going to change the default definition of public directory from `public` to `public_html` and next lines provides a relative path to your setPublicPath value.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this works great, except for vue. it compiles css and js in the proper folder, (in my case it is /../public_html) but they dont work. when it compiles the app.js it does not take the path of the .vue files into account: `./resources/js/components/SetBgImg.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&":`, should be `./../projectname/resources/js/components/SetBgImg.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&":` how can this be fixed`?

Comment: Don't forget restarting `npm run` to let changes take effect.

Comment: I dont use vue but nowadays this answer indeed works for localhost and i rid off of copypasting  assets to synced project's public folder  in the cloud each damn time.

Answer (score 9):

Go to this address:

```
/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

and append this code to end of file:

```
public function register()
{   $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since Laravel version 10 there is a [new way](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#public-path-binding) to change the path. So in your service provider do this:

```php
public function register()
{
    $app->usePublicPath(__DIR__.'/../../public_html');
    /* old version code
    $this->app->bind('path.public', fn() => base_path() . '/public_html';);
    */
}
```

Comment: All the above solutions didn't work for me, only this did. Thanks.

Comment: It's work with me 

Comment: `$app->usePublicPath(str_replace('bootstrap', '', __DIR__).'\mysite.com');`

Comment: Updated Laravel from 8 to 10;
$this->app->usePublicPath(__DIR__.'/../../public_html'); worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Just want to update all previous answers, if your public_html is not inside laravel folder, then you need to use this code:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
   return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple root directory create .htaccess file and add code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that need to change the public path so that it is also available to Artisan, add the following to `bootstrap/app.php`, just after the last `singleton` method:

```php
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return base_path("<your public directory name>");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

These answers did not work for laravel 5.5, but my own method can help you.

Step 1: Discard all files except the public file to the main directory on the server.

Step 2: Public file to the public_html file on the server.

Step 3: Pull index.php file from public_html and change it like this.

Step 3A:

Orginal -> `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Changes -> `require __DIR__.'/../**created_folder**/vendor/autoload.php';`

Original -> `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

Changes -> `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../**Created_folder**/bootstrap/app.php';`

Step 4: Create symlinkcreate.php

Step 4A: `<?php 
symlink('/home/**server_directory**/**created_folder**/storage/app/public','/home/**server_directory**/public_html/storage');`

Step 4B: yourwebsite.com/symlinkcreate.php visit

Step 4C: symlinkcreate.php delete your server.

Finally, the directory structure looks like this:

```
/etc
/logs
/lscache
/mail
/Your_Created_Folder
  ../LARAVEL_FOLDERS
/public_html
  ../css
  ../js
  ../.htaccess
  ../index.php
  ../web.config
/ssl
/tmp
```

Finish.

Laravel 5.5 public_html sorunu için bu cevabı gönül rahatlığıyla kullanabilirsiniz.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution as for me is to create symbolic link.

1. Make backup of your `public_html` folder.
2. Connect to your server via `ssh`.
3. In my particular scenario, whole application is located in `~/laravel` folder.
4. Now you have to be in the `~/` folder:
5. Run `rm -r public_html`. This command will delete public_html folder and all its contents.
6. Make symbolic link `ln -s $(pwd)/laravel/public $(pwd)/public_html`. `$(pwd)` will be substituted with absolute path from root of the server.
7. Now you should be able to see desired result.

Comment: I don't know why this is not getting more upvotes? It's such a good solution, instead of making changes to the code. Thank you kind stranger.

Answer (score 3):

It took two days for me to figure out but finally I deployed my Laravel-project to my cPanel webhosting by doing next steps:

1. Change the server.php file as following:

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__ . '/public_html' .$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/public_html/index.php';
```

2. Change webpack.mix.js as following:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public_html/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

3. Change the name of "public" folder in Laravel-project to "public_html" and upload the code to the root directory cPanel. Make sure that you have a back-up from the current public_html directory. If you have the correct PHP version on your hosting and edited .env file then everything should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `bootstrap/app.php`:

   Add

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() {
     return __DIR__;
   });
   ```

   right after

   ```
   $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
     realpath(__DIR__)
   );
   ```
2. Fixing `server.php`:

   Change

   ```
   if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
     return false;
   }

   require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
   ```

   to

   ```
   if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
     return false;
   }

   require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
   ```
3. In `.gitignore`, change

   ```
   /public/hot
   /public/storage
   ```

   to

   ```
   /public_html/hot
   /public_html/storage
   ```
4. In `webpack.mix.js`, change

   ```
   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
     .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
   ```

   to

   ```
   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
     .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/css');
   ```

I'm still looking for a fix for the `asset()` function, which remains broken...

Answer (score 0):

For me none of this worked until I changed the root public folder in server settings. In production it is in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<your_site_name>`. Edit it with a text editor and just scroll until you see root path pointing to `/public` folder. Change that to whatever is your new public folder and restart the server. On local, I had to change path in `Homestead.yaml` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<your_site_name>` after I SSHed into Vagrant. `vagrant reload --provision` to make sure it caught on. Then I also edited `index.php` and registered a new path in the service provider just in case, but it seems to work without it. I don't use any 3rd party dependencies with Laravel though so I don't know if this will work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the contents of `/public` folder of your laravel application in:
   `public_html` or a subfolder in case of subdomain.
2. Put all other laravel folders and files in a new folder in the top
   level of the `public_html` folder for example

```
/home/{yourcpanelfoldername}/{applicationname}
```

3. open file named `index.php` in the public folder and replace all

```
    __DIR__.'/../
```

with

```
    __DIR__.'/../../{applicationname}/
```

4. For laravel versions `< 10` put this line

```
    $app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return __DIR__;
    });
```

just after this line

```
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../{applicationname}/bootstrap/app.php';
```

5. For laravel version `>= 10` add this line

```
    $app->usePublicPath(__DIR__);
```

just after this line

```
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../{applicationname}/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me in Laravel 10.

First, you must create the folder `public_html` or other name you want.

**IMPORTANT:** Don't delete the default `public` folder, create a new one.

Open the file `bootstrap/app.php` and after this section:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

Paste this code:

```
$app->usePublicPath($app->basePath('public_html'));
```

Where `public_html` is the public folder you have created.

[Reference:](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-10-change-public-folder-to-public-html-on-shared-server)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10, open `public/index.php` file.

Add the following line after `$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);`

```
app()->usePublicPath(__DIR__);
```