# move laravel to live web

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have my website which its my resume and now I want to show the project that I have done one of my project is laravel and I move it to: public_html/laravel
and also move my DB to there but I get this error:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /laravel/ on this server.

I don't understand is it because of I didn't put files on main public_html and move it to folder or other stuff I also changes(i don't know if its right) change config/database.php mysql part to database configuration but I keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Laravel server files from the `public/` directory. So try a URL like this instead:

http://example.com/laravel/public

If that works, you'll need to move some files around a bit. This should help with moving things around:

[How to change public folder to public_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for your answer it is worked somehow because before that i only get error that i said on blank page but now i see error but its laravel error so its work i think but this is error i get do you know the solution?                                                                                                                                                                                                                        FatalErrorException in MySqlConnector.php line 27:
Call to a member function exec() on null

Comment: Glad I could help. Sound like you now have a different issue and should start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared hosting then please do not uplaod whole laravel application to the `publitc_html` folder. You have to upload your all application at global document root for your domain like `home/yourdomain`and you have to **rename existing public_html folder to any name** and **rename laravel public folder to public_html** and try again. See the image below:
[image]