# Laravel structure broken after deploying in shared host

Tags: laravel

i am deploying my project to shared hosting now. But i found that all the css file seem like not in correct directory. For example my original code is `<link href="{{ asset('intro/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

In server i need to change it to
`<link href="public/intro/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` in order to make it work.
But i having thousand of line need to change if i had to update all.
Is there others way to do it?
I am using Cpanel and my file is located in public_html.

Comment: Have you tried this solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<link href="{{URL:: asset('intro/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```