# Laravel .htaccess redirect to main page when accessing url.com/public

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

My website runs in the following url **www.mywebsite.com** without any problem. So, when creating the project I applied some `.htaccess` rules in my root folder, as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove www    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com$1 [R=301,L]

    # Remove http and force https   
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

The issue is that if I access `www.mywebsite.com/public` I still view the website but without the CSS applied (because the URL is wrong).

How can I redirect the URL `www.mywebsite.com/public` to `www.mywebsite.com`, without set on fire my urls `www.mywebsite.com/public/img/someimage.png`?

---

**Edit**: To make myself clear:

```
www.mywebsite.com -> it's working -> I don't want to change that

www.mywebsite.com/public/img/someimage.png -> it's working -> I don't want to change that

www.mywebsite.com/public -> It's working -> I see my website without the CSS applied -> I WANT to change this by redirecting users to www.mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Set your Apache `DocumentRoot` correctly to point at the `public` folder.

Comment: @ceejayoz it's a shared hosting.

Comment: Most shared hosts have a `httpdocs`, `public`, `public_html`, etc. folder within a non-web-accessible parent folder. If that's the case, put Laravel's `public` folder in there (and consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5 if it's not called `public`). If that's *not* the case, find a better host.

Comment: (Side note: If you're wondering *why* this is so important, check out this Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=db_password+filetype%3Aenv)

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think you understand the problem. I'm gonna edit the post.

Comment: I do understand the problem. Having Laravel's non-public files (`.env`, `storage`, etc.) accessible to the web is a severely dangerous thing. You should fix it, as I advised above.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't have the .env file exposed to the web. The file permission is `640` and you can't access through www.mywebsite.com/.env. That issue has nothing to do with the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @ceejayoz and where do I say that something outside public/ is available to the internet? I'm really not following. My `index.php` is on the public/ folder. The only thing my .htaccess does is allow my website to be access (and viewed) through `www.mywebsite.com`. You can't view/access ANY folder/file outside `public/` folder.

Comment: So if you go to URLs like `www.mywebsite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log` or `www.mywebsite.com/config/database.php` you get a 404?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I do.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your file structure, then? You've done something odd if your `public` folder isn't one level inside the folder containing the rest of Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz what do you mean by one level inside? My structure is: `public_html/laravel` and the `public` folder is inside: `public_html/laravel/public/`.

Comment: Why aren't your URLs like `www.mywebsite.com/laravel/public/img/someimage.png` then?

Comment: Are `www.mywebsite.com/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log` or `www.mywebsite.com/laravel/config/database.php` 404s?

Comment: @ceejayoz I thought you'd understand "laravel" stands for all the files from the laravel installation. Correction then: `public_html/all_files_from_laravel/public/`

Comment: That means your non-public Laravel files are in the `public_html` folder, and thus directly accessible to the web. That's a security problem. Up to you if you care, I suppose.

Comment: @ceejayoz dude, they are not accessible, how many times do I have to tell you that? If I access `www.mywebsite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log` I get 404. If I access `www.mywebsite.com/config/database.php` I get 404. If I access `www.mywebsite.com/.env` I get 404.

Comment: I'm not giving confusing structureinfo, I didn't changed the Laravel initial structure, the code is working without any security problems. I don't have to ask myself why. The file exists in the FTP but you can't access throught browser. Why is it hard for you to understand?

Comment: @ceejayoz do you want to go on a private chat and I show you my project URL so you can test and check for your self? I'm pretty ok with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

By editing the file `/public_html/public/index.php` I can check if the current URL matches my criteria.

In my case whenever the string `public` is present in the URL it always have two slashes (because of the `.htaccess`), like:

`www.mywebsite.com/public/`

With that said, in the top of the file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/public/')
{
    header('location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, what you are doing is **highly dangerous**. Do not make anything outside of your `public` folder avalible.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards as I said in my post, nothing outside the `public` folder is available.

Comment: Your post is very confusing. But, you have said that all the files for your project are in `public_html`, thus they are accessible. Sure you’ve changed a file permission and added a .htaccess, but things change, file permissions change, new packages are added – anything. All we are trying to say is that it is a high security risk and you should be warey of it. There are enough people saying the same thing that you should not be arrogant enough to assume you know better – you do not. If your host is bad, use a different one. Best of luck to you, I mean no offense – but this is a warning.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards isn't it impressive that me telling you that something doesn't work you consider that arrogant just because your theory does not work? 
If it's so important to you that code is not in the `public_html` please hack the 90% of websites that have their code in the `public_html`, such as Wordpress sites. Feel free to amaze me. If you want, I can tell you my project URL in private and be my guest to try access private files. No offense.

Comment: I have offered you my advice, other people have also said the same thing. You have chosen to ignore it. No problem.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards you also have chosen to ignore what I said, no problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should never allow access to anything outside of your `public` folder.

Your server should be setup to go to `public`, not the main folder above it. Do not move your `index.php` file from the `public` folder.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had moved the `index.php` file but I have not. But my problem persists.