# Laravel error with Public_path is not working

Tags: laravel

To move to a server, I overwrite the **public_path()** in App Providers using this code:

```
  public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return base_path().'/public_html/img';
    });
}
```

But instead of getting

```
/home/domain/img/image.jpg
```

I have

```
/Home/domain/laravelprojectname/public_html/img/image.jpg
```

Can someone help ? Thank you.

Comment: This is because your app's code lives in `/Home/domain/laravelprojectname/public_html` on the server. What is the issue here, does the image not exist at the path?

Comment: i solved that by changing the code to return base_path().'/../public_html/img';  
But still i dont understand  why it's happened

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5).