# Need help on Laravel frontend issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

Can't figure out what's wrong on my project, Chrome Dev Tools returns an error on app.js at line 1:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `app.js:1`

Clicking on error highlight, Developers Tools shows an html code rather the javascript "webpacked" sentences.

[image]

Note the `src` attribute descripted in the image above, has a bad url:

> src="http://localhost:8000/**js/app.js/js/app.js**"

I supose that would be `http://localhost:8000/js/app.js`

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
    .setPublicPath('public_html/')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/admin/admin.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css')
    .copy('resources/assets/img', 'img');
```

**app.php**

This snippet is added before `return $app;` into `bootstrap/app.php` file to tell to Laravel that the public folder must be `public_html`

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path() . '/public_html';
});
```

PHP serves the application without errors. The only error is about frontend. Curiously, the css compiled files serves ok and loads right but not like that the app.js script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change public folder to public\_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Check that all closing quotes are properly closed, tags has relevant closing tags. Use IDE with good code highlighting.