# Prevent access to Laravel through /public/ directory using .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I've set up a Laravel project on a shared hosting where the document root can't be set to Laravel's "public" folder. To get around this, I use the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^habbo.gallery$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.habbo.gallery$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

This works fine. I can access my project through "https://domain.tld" now. However, the project is also still accessible through "https://domain.tld/public/" which is what I would like to prevent. I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, so I was wondering if this is possible at all using only .htaccess.

Comment: You could try to rename `public` folder to `public_html` or whatever name used in your hosting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5

Comment: You can try to redirect `https://domain.tld/public/` to `https://domain.tld`.

Comment: @HTMHell Wait a second..that could actually work. Currently everything is in public_html (which is the doc root), but maybe I could move everything up 1 directory, and do as you said?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev Yup I've been trying that, maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it gives me an infinite loop of redirects

Comment: @Metoniem Yes, that would probably be a better solution.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why I hadn't thought of that @HTMHell, that might require a bit of editing in other Laravel files though? I'll have to check that out

Comment: I suggest put your `public/` in `/mydomain.tld/public_html/` then the whole laravel app in a directory on the same level as `public_html`, but don't forget to update your `public/index.php` to point to that laravel app directory, that's the way I do it on shared hosting

Comment: @xDiff I'll try that too! thanks

Comment: @Metoniem Is it must that you should use htaccess? If you want I can show you another way. ok?

Comment: @Saularis not a must, but preferred! feel free to answer the question with your way, I've been experimenting with methods from the comments but haven't got one to work yet

Comment: Ok, wait. Submitting an answer.

Comment: @Metoniem Check my answer, test and update me. Btw I just tested before sharing. It works.

Comment: Marked my own question as duplicate because the accepted answer has answered my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Copy two file from public folder and paste them to root folder.
Two Files are: `index.php` and `.htaccess`

Then open `index.php` file on an editor which is pasted on the root folder. Then replace two lines with some changes as shown below. See comments on code where I said **Replace this by following code**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

// require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; Replace this by following code
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/
// $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; Replace this by following code
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```