# How to host laravel website on godaddy hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

Recently , I bought godaddy hosting to host my laravel project and i got a domain name and and pushed my laravel project to public_html file and then search my primary domain on internet but it did not work . Can anyone help me in hosting my first site on internet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change public folder to public\_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)

Comment: This [deploy-laravel-on-godaddy](https://medium.com/@Bohr/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting-godaddy-953758dc57ac) might be helpful for you.

Comment: @kam1234, I also have domain registered on GoDaddy and do not know how to make website for myself. May I ask for your help please? Where should I start from?

Comment: do not know how to make website for myself ? Do you want to learn how to build web application or website ? );