# Laravel - Public_path() on live server

Tags: laravel, path, public

I have uploaded my laravel Site to my host..

My Structure is this:

```
/home/username/mylaravelproject/ <- contains everything
/home/username/public_html/ <- contains my public folder
```

so basically I moved my `public` folder to `../public_html/`

Now my Public_Path() function does not work properly.

I tried a few different posts, and the one with the closes result was this one:
[How to change public folder to public_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)

but it returns a wrong path...

It returns this:
"/home/username/mylaravelproject/public_html/"

What am I supposed to do in order to configure it properly so that artisan works and the function in php too?

Comment: Have you tried running composer update?

Comment: Have you tried this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5
?

Comment: @HamishGibson yes, no change...

Comment: @AntonNémeth uh... thats the very same link i posted in my request... :)

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues often rise up when migrating installations. I think you can solve it by reconfiguring your htaccess file (in case your webserver is running apache) as shown here: https://www.webhostface.com/kb/knowledgebase/laravel-public-folder/.

Otherwise, to answer your question concretely:
Since you already have a function outputting this part correctly:
/home/username/mylaravelproject/public_html/
Why not rebind path.public to the function you used to get this output + "public/".

Although this might not be the nicest solution, and I'm sure there's better ones, this will probably work