# Blade Parent CSS not called if route is one level lower

Tags: php, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an admin interface for a web application.

The full directory structure is as follows:

```
|-main
| |- app
| |- bootstrap
| |- config
| |- database
| |- resources
|   | -views
|     |-admin
|      |-templates
|       |-template.blade.php
|      |-utils
|       |-foot.blade.php
|       |-head.blade.php
|     |-views
|       |-index.blade.php
|       |-users.blade.php
| |- routes
|   |- web.php
|
|-public_html
| |-admindash
|   |-dist
|     |-css
|     |-img
|     |-js
|   |-plugins
|     |-bootstrap
|     |-fontawesome-free
|     |-jquery
```

The head.blade file looks something close to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>...</title>

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admindash/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
.
.
some more css here
.
.

</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
```

foot.blade:

```
<script src="../admindash/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script 
.
.
.
More scripts here
.
.
.

</body>
</html>
```

The template blade then includes both of these and yields a section for child blades to populate:

```
@include('admin.utils.head')

<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
        @yield('maincontent')
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->

</div>

@include('admin.utils.foot')
```

And then with the index and users blades in views folders I do the following

```
@extends('admin.templates.template')

@section('maincontent')
.
.
main html goes here
.
.
@endsection
```

All works fine to this point, I define my Controller functions which return the blade files and my web.php routes I define as well:

```
//Admin Dashboard routes
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function (){
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@adminHome')->name('AdminDashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/maintenance/users', 'DashboardController@displayUsers')->name('AdminDashboardUsers');
});
```

When I load the route /admin/dashboard the styles render perfectly, no errors. Tricky part is when I render /admin/maintenance/users then it all goes off, I get a skeleton html file with an error in console that the css resources could not be loaded.

NOTE: the css and js files are all located in a public_html folder outside of the project folder.

Comment: Because you are using relative Url... Please show the clear folder structure.

Comment: ive edited to add the full directory structure

Comment: So you are renamed `public` to `public_html` right?

Comment: no, this project is running on shared hosting so I have to drop in the bootstrap template files in the public_html (publicly accessible) folder and the actual application code in a separate folder....so main and public_html are basically on the same level directory-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your are using **Relative URL**. You need to use **Full URL** instead of **Relative**. And you are approaching **Wrong Way** to deploy your laravel in **Shared Hosting**.

---

**Solution**

Just put full url for all `css` and `js` files, Like below,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/admindash/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
```

---

### Best Practise (for Shared Hosting)

- Change laravel `public` directory to `public_html`. ([Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5))
- Use `url()` or `URL::assert()` function to generate assert/full URLs ([Refer Here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls))

[How to deploy Laravel Application in Shared Hosting?](https://medium.com/@Bohr/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting-godaddy-953758dc57ac)