# How to change public directory to public_html directory for Laravel Mix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mix, sweetalert

I'm using Laravel 8 and I wanted to install Sweet Alert. So after downloading it and adding `require('sweetalert');` to `bootstrap.js`, I ran the command `npm run production`.

Then I have included this in my `master.blade.php`:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@include('sweet::alert')
```

Now because I had changed my public directory from `public` to `public_html`, Laravel  `asset()` function would call the `public_html/js/app.js` and this is wrong because Laravel Mix generated `app.js` and `app.css` in the `public` directory.

So the question is how can I change the default generation of Laravel Mix which is `public` to `public_html` ?

Here is my `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function(){
            return base_path() . '/public_html';
        });
    }
```

Comment: Laravel is written to assume the public directory is named `public`. Changing it is a bad idea.

Comment: Can't you create a symlink from public_html to public? This will solve your problem without creating another problems

Comment: @EliasSoares I don't get what you mean by symlink! Would you explain more plz?

Comment: @nitinos Mix has a solution for this built-in. I've added an answer below.

Comment: do check how symbolic link used here: [config](https://gist.github.com/johanvanhelden/29096a9ff31eac9b039d36056919abbb)
and other stuff here : [laravel mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/faq)
It will help you understand the things plus symlink is actually a symbolic link and comes in very handy when you have multiple framework installations. By creating symbolic links you create alias for directories without changing actual name.check here [symlink](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/symlink-tutorial-in-linux-how-to-create-and-remove-a-symbolic-link/)

Comment: A better solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Alfian has answered your question. But the solution you asked for, is not recommended when you are talking about renaming the **public** folder. You should not really rename your public folder while using Laravel.

But I can understand why you renamed it, to declare the default root folder. But there are better solutions instead of renaming it. And then there will be no such question too.

**Best Solution:** Upload the Laravel project as it is in the **public_html** folder. Go to your cPanel and enter Domains/Addon Domains/Subdomains (which type domain you are using) section and just change the **Document Root** as **/public_html/public**. You are done.

**Update:**

If it's a primary domain or addon domain there may not be an option directly to change the document root. Then we can just add a rule in the .htaccess file. Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change configuration compiled assets directory on webpack config files, by default laravel set webpack at webpack.config.js

Here more documentation about compiling assets laravel

[Laravel 8 Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix)

Answer (score 0):

In .env change `ASSET_URL=https://yourdomain.com/public_html`. But its a bad practice to have index along with php code(app, vendor, etc..)

You can create symbolic link from public to act as public html like follows

`ln -s /full/work/path/laravel-project/public /full/work/path/public_html`

But you might need to remove public_html first

`mv public_html tmp`

I assume your structure would be

```
full/work/path/
   - laravel-project
       - public
   - public_html
   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

in the main root directory of laravel project one file server.php and  another one index.php

first, delete the index.php file
after that rename the server.php file to index.php

after that, you can use it directly as yourdomainname.example

From,
dhayal info tech web solutions