# How relocate public folder in Laravel 8, 9?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-9

How to change Laravel 8 and Laravel 9 public folder to any other name and relocate the public folder to different path? Example: all Laravel files to folder "laravel_project" and public directory set as "public_html".

Folders structure for example:

```
/main_folder
   /laravel_project
      /app
      /bootstrap
      /config
      /...
   /public_html
      /.htaccess
      /favicon.ico
      /index.php
      /robots.txt
   /other_folders
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change public folder to public\_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)