# Path of images inside public_html in cpanel inside Laravel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-9, public-html

In cpanel, the entire content of the site is inside the AryaBMS file, and I put only the public folder, which contains images, index.php, htaccess, etc., into public_html.

[image: Cpanel]

I want a notification in Telegram that is done through a cron job, I want to send a notification to the Telegram group after an hour and it works in the localhost because the public folder is inside the main folder, but in CPanel the public folder is inside public_html.
The only problem is to get the image, here I said (local host) public_path, but inside cpanel, the images are located in the side folder of the whole project (AryaBMS), that is, inside public_html
How can I give an address here so that he can read the photo?
Please help me ♥️

[image]

Comment: Im really confused.. where is the laravel folder? is it inside public_html folder or AryaBMS? or outside? also please modify your question to simplify the problem and what you want to accomplish

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

do you have .htaccess file inside public_html ?
if you don't then create .htaccess file with `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` inside.