# how can i change my upload path to public_html instead of public

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, cpanel, laravel-9

i shared a laravel project in Cpannel

but i seprated the public path from main project path and i didn't upload whole of project in public_html.

i upload the project in a new folder and moved the contents of public folder to public_html for security issues.

i adjusted some path in index.php and the website runs properly..

the huge problem is that the functions related to upload images , upload files in public

and can't recognize the public_html as a root path.

my disk:

```
    `'real_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],`
```

my function:

```
 `public function store(){
    $rand=rand('0','480');
    $IMGname=date('YmdHi').'_'.'article'.$rand.'.'.$this->image->extension();
    $this->image->storeAs('upload/articles',$IMGname,'real_public');
   }`
```

i try these to fix the problem

1- edit server.php in laravel-core folder and change /public to /../public_html
2- edit register method in AppServiceProviver.php

```
  `$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
});`
```

but it didn't work

another way that i tested :

```
  ` 'real_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => dirname(__DIR__,2).'/public_html',
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],`
```

and unfortunately didn't work

another solutions in stakeoverflow had same result

Comment: The similar question was asked before. You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel

Comment: ye i see but as i said , all of solutions in stakeoverflow didn't work for me  @ryanicle

Comment: What is the error you are currently facing after the first try? Could you please provide more details?