Laravel 10, No input file specified
I have recently deployed a new Laravel App to a cPanel server. However, when I try to access the website, I encounter an error message saying "No input file specified." Additionally, the server log shows the following error: "AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /home/user/public_html/index.php (Operation not permitted).'"
I have checked that the file exists at the specified path, and the file permissions seem to be correct. I am unsure of what might be causing this issue. Could someone please help me understand the possible causes and provide guidance on how to resolve this error?
Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

The app is built using Laravel 10.
The cPanel server is running the latest version, and all services appear to be functioning properly.
I have tried restarting the server and checking the Apache configuration, but the issue persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this problem. Thank you in advance!
I have tried restarting the server and checking the Apache configuration, but the issue persists.

Are you deploying the app using its normal files and folders structure? so everything is over public_html? In that case I think you should modify some files because laravel is looking for public and not public_html folder. Maybe this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder-location

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

The No input file specified is a message you are presented with because of the implementation of PHP on your server, which in this case indicates a CGI implementation (can be verified with phpinfo()).
Your cPanel is probably running Apache. This means that your public folder's .htaccess is checking whether the Apache module for URL rewriting is enabled. If that's not the case, the CGI implementation cannot retrieve the information needed for displaying your routes, which usually is passed via PATH_INFO to your Laravel router.
Verify that you have a valid .htaccess in your public folder, that the mod_rewrite module is enabled in your Apache installation, and then you should be ready to go.
